# R: Moving data between two data.tables using match in j

Tags: r, data.table, match

I have this reproducible data:

```
cola <- letters[1:3]
colb <- letters[11:13]
key <- paste0(cola,colb)
dt1 <- data.table(cola,colb, key)
setkey(dt1, "key")                  
dt2 <- rbind(dt1, dt1)
dt2$toget <- LETTERS[1:nrow(dt2)]
colnames(dt2)[colnames(dt2)=="key"] <- "key2"
setkey(dt2, "key2")
dt1;dt2
   cola colb key
1:    a    k  ak
2:    b    l  bl
3:    c    m  cm
   cola colb key2 toget
1:    a    k   ak     A
2:    a    k   ak     D
3:    b    l   bl     B
4:    b    l   bl     E
5:    c    m   cm     C
6:    c    m   cm     F
```

I would like to create a column called `retrieved` in dt1 to retrieve the values of `toget` from dt2 whith row numbers based on the first match of `key` in `key2`

---

EDIT: benchmarking my simple `match` solution against Akrun's more elegant `join` shows a speed advantage to the simple `match` based solution... wonder why

```
> microbenchmark(
+ dt1[,toget:= dt2[,toget[match(key,key2)]]],
+ dt1[dt2, toget := toget, on = .(key = key2), mult = "first"]
+ )
Unit: microseconds
                                                             expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval
               dt1[, `:=`(toget, dt2[, toget[match(key, key2)]])] 433.2 444.55 477.485 455.45 470.45 1125.6   100
 dt1[dt2, `:=`(toget, toget), on = .(key = key2), mult = "first"] 624.3 637.70 665.088 648.70 679.60  819.0   100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yeah I just found it, the below works

```
> dt1[,toget:= dt2[,toget[match(key,key2)]]]
> dt1
   cola colb key toget
1:    a    k  ak     A
2:    b    l  bl     B
3:    c    m  cm     C
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use a join

```
library(data.table)
dt1[dt2, toget := toget, on = .(key = key2), mult = "first"]
```